# play vimeo video in landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, vimeo-player, vimeo-ios

hi i am trying to play embedded vimeo video in uiwebview. when i click the webview, the video begins to play in default player in portrait mode, when i click the full screen button, the video only zooms in portait mode, not turning to landscape mode. please advice how to play vimeo videos in landscape mode as well. thanks in advance

```
    let embedHTML="<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body {background-color: transparent;color: black;}</style><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes\"/></head><body style=\"margin:0\"><div><iframe src=\"//player.vimeo.com/video/139785390?autoplay=1&amp;title=1&amp;byline=1&amp;portrait=0\" width=\"640\" height=\"360\" frameborder=\"0\" webkit-playsinline webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div></body></html>"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://vimeo.com/139785390")!
    webView.loadHTMLString(embedHTML as String, baseURL:url as URL )
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    webView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
```

Comment: in here `width=\"640\" height=\"360` change the device width and height

Comment: what to change here? @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik tried changing with device width and height still no use

Comment: better is this possible to attach the project i will check